# Publicly traded instrument analogous to a bond with discount rate equal to a stock dividend rate

Tags: bond, dividends, discounting

Suppose we have a stock paying a stochastic dividend at rate $q$ in a zero interest rate environment. Is there a publicly traded (non-over-the-counter, meaning not specially designed for an entity) instrument, synthesized or not, with present value $\mathbf E[e^{-\int_0^t q\,d\tau}]$ at time $t=0$? It is analogous to a bond with discount rate set at the dividend rate.

Comment: i suspect you'll be able to get reasonably close to this payoff using div futures, but i'm not aware of anything which matches this exactly...

Comment: Are you looking for an instrument that will pay $1$ at time $t$ for certain and that has a present value of $\mathbf E[e^{-\int_0^t q\,d\tau}]$, today,i.e. a cash flow "discounted" at the yield rate?

Comment: @Kermittfrog: Yes. I suppose you are hinting it does not work by the arbitrage argument.

Comment: Thanks. That condition was not clear to me from your question. I find the question is really interesting, but I have no ansatz at hand.